# Need help getting JSON.parse() to work (Discord Bot)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I have a seperate JSON file which is linked as

```
const Players = require('./Database/Players.json');
```

and a praser that goes through the code

```
client.on('message', message => {


    if (message.content.toLowerCase() ==='smack activate') {
        
        let PlayerData = [message.author.username];

        Activate [message.author.username] = {
        AccountActive: 1,
        Health: 100,
        Level: 1,
        Lust: 0,
        Items: ""
        };

        var parsedata = JSON.parse(Players)   // <-----------
        if (parsedata.PlayerData.accountactive === 1) {
            message.channel.send ("Account Already Activated");
            return;
        }

        fs.writeFile("./Database/Players.json", JSON.stringify (Activate, null, 4), err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            message.channel.send ("Account Activated")
        });
    };
```

But nothing seems to work..
what am I doing wrong?
I'm getting this error message

```
undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^
```

Comment: Why are you parsing it if it's already a JSON data.

Comment: @DeekshithHegde If I don't parse it I get an error saying the = sign is wrong in 
if (Players.PlayerData.accountactive = 1) {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you are trying to do the following:

1. Check if the message author is a known player with an activated account.
2. If yes - send the message that the account is already activated and return.
3. Otherwise - add the new player data to the known players.

You probably can do this in this following way:

```
const Players = require('./Database/Players.json');

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'smack activate') {

    const PlayerData = Players[message.author.username];

    if (PlayerData && (PlayerData.AccountActive === 1)) {
      message.channel.send("Account Already Activated");
      return;
    }

    Players[message.author.username] = {
      AccountActive: 1,
      Health: 100,
      Level: 1,
      Lust: 0,
      Items: ""
    };

    fs.writeFile("./Database/Players.json", JSON.stringify(Players, null, 4), err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      message.channel.send("Account Activated")
    });
  };

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how `require` works. As described in the documentation:
https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together

> LOAD_AS_FILE(X)
>
> 1. If X is a file, load X as its file extension format. STOP
> 2. If X.js is a file, load X.js as JavaScript text. STOP
> 3. **If X.json is a file, parse X.json to a JavaScript Object. STOP**
> 4. If X.node is a file, load X.node as binary addon. STOP

So you should not call `JSON.parse`, because `require` automatically parses json modules into JavaScript objects.

Comment: I see that's helpful to know. So I did take out JSON.parse but now getting error that the = sign is wrong

Comment: @Yuzi I see, can you please print the content of `Players` variable to console and share it here (if it does not contain sensitive information)?

Comment: Yes I can do that for you